# Spring scheduler fixed delay based on time of day

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

All,

Is there a way I can use spring scheduler which changes the fixedRate based on time of day?

For eg: a method should run with a rate of 1000ms for 10-12am
And then switch to 5000ms after 12am

Or do I have to create multiple methods with different crons?

Comment: If we're talking about Quartz scheduler, then yes you should be able to define a complex trigger. I can't unfortunately provide an answer from the top of my head, if nobody answers I'll come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html), try this:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledConfiguration {
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "* * 10-11 * * ?")
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * 0-9,12-23 * * ?")
    public void execScheduledTask() {
        System.out.println("Now: " + new Date());
    }
    
}
```

You need to use two cron configurations:

* * 10-11 * * ?: every second, of every minute, if the hour part of today is 10 or 11, of every day, of every month, every day of the week.

0/5 * 0-9,12-23 * * ?: every 5 seconds starting at 0 seconds, of every minute, if the hour part of today is between 0 and 9 or between 12 and 23, of every day, of every month, every day of the week

See more about this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduling-annotations)

Comment: And how would the cron expression look like if the time range is for eg 10:30 to 10:35 am with 5s delay and rest with 1min delay. I got the cron for 5 s delay '*/5 30-35 9 * * ?' but not sure how to add 1min delay for the rest of the day

Comment: You mean execute every 5 seconds between 10:30:00 and 10:35:59, and every one minute every other hour? I think it would be '0/5 30-34 10 * * ?' the first cron (every 5 seconds betweem 10:30:00 and 10:34:59), the second would be '0 0-29 10 * * ?' (every minute from 10:00:00 to 10:29:59), the third '0 35-59 10 * * ?' (every minute from 10:30:00 to 10:59:59) and the fourth '0 * 0-9, 11-23 * * ? ' (every minute from 00:00:00 to 09:59:59 or from 11:00:00 to 23:59:59). I don't see a way to reduce the number of crons.